# cannot send emails with Amazon SES .NET SDK

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can send emails with SMTP option in .Net but I need to use .NET SDK to send emails via Amazon. It gives me error that says "Email address is not verified", event though I am sure that it is verified. By the way, I am using a Test Account(SandBox).

What am I doing wrong? or am I missing anything?

here is my code,

```
var sesClient = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient("AKIAJHXXXXXXXXXXX", "RVGdbCKXILwjUIKSexKlwXXXXXXXXXXXX",Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
var dest = new Destination
{
    ToAddresses = new List<string>() { "tayfun.ural@aryxxx.com" },
    CcAddresses = new List<string>() { "arif.yilmaz@aryxxx.com" }
};

var from = "tayfun.ural@aryxxx.com";
var subject = new Content("You're invited to the meeting");
var body = new Body(new Content("Please join us Monday at 7:00 PM."));
var msg = new Message(subject, body);

var request = new SendEmailRequest
{
    Destination = dest,
    Message = msg,
    Source = from
};

var verify = sesClient.VerifyEmailAddress(new VerifyEmailAddressRequest { EmailAddress =     "tayfun.ural@aryada.com" });

try
{
   var response = sesClient.SendEmail(request);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Amazon SES in sandbox/test mode, all from/to/cc addresses must be verified email addresses. The error "Email address is not verified" means that atleast one of the email addresses is not verified. It could be the TO, FROM, CC, or BCC.

In your case, ensure that both "tayfun.ural@aryxxx.com" and "arif.yilmaz@aryxxx.com" are verified and/or that "aryxxx.com" is a verified domain.

Answer (score 1):

```
        String FROM = "SENDER@EXAMPLE.COM";  // Replace with your "From" address. This address must be verified.
        String TO = "RECIPIENT@EXAMPLE.COM"; // Replace with a "To" address. If you have not yet requested
        // production access, this address must be verified.

        String SUBJECT = "Amazon SES test (AWS SDK for .NET)";
        String BODY = "This email was sent through Amazon SES by using the AWS SDK for .NET.";

        // Construct an object to contain the recipient address.
        Destination destination = new Destination();
        destination.ToAddresses = (new List<string>() { TO });

        // Create the subject and body of the message.
        Content subject = new Content(SUBJECT);
        Content textBody = new Content(BODY);
        Body body = new Body(textBody);

        // Create a message with the specified subject and body.
        Message message = new Message(subject, body);

        // Assemble the email.
        SendEmailRequest request = new SendEmailRequest(FROM, destination, message);

        // Choose the AWS region of the Amazon SES endpoint you want to connect to. Note that your production 
        // access status, sending limits, and Amazon SES identity-related settings are specific to a given 
        // AWS region, so be sure to select an AWS region in which you set up Amazon SES. Here, we are using 
        // the US East (N. Virginia) region. Examples of other regions that Amazon SES supports are USWest2 
        // and EUWest1. For a complete list, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html 
        Amazon.RegionEndpoint REGION = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1;

        // Instantiate an Amazon SES client, which will make the service call.
        AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(REGION);

        // Send the email.
        try
        {
            //("Attempting to send an email through Amazon SES by using the AWS SDK for .NET...");
            client.SendEmail(request);
            //("Email sent!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //("The email was not sent.");
            //("Error message: " + ex.Message);
        }
```